# My iPhone 4 running on 4.2.1 and I was wondering if I could restore the phone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, restore

My iPhone 4 running on 4.2.1 and I was wondering if I could restore the phone to the same firmware by dowloading the original firmware and holding SHIFT in iTunes and clicking restore???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may restore your iPhone to 4.2.1, but you need the SHSHs for your device as Apple servers only allow 4.3 firmware at the moment, I think.